# IIS Compression setting for batch request mime type 'multipart/mixed'

Tags: http, iis, compression, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api service that accepts batch requests from a web app.  I have defined the mime type 'multipart/*' to be compressed in the web.config but the response is not compressed.  I'm not sure why it is not working as normal single requests (not sent as a multipart/mixed are compressed fine).

```
 <httpCompression>
  <dynamicTypes>
    <clear />
    <add enabled="true" mimeType="text/*" />
    <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/javascript" />
    <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/json" />
    <add enabled="true" mimeType="multipart/*" />
    <add enabled="false" mimeType="*/*" />
  </dynamicTypes>
  <staticTypes>
    <clear />
    <add enabled="true" mimeType="text/*" />
    <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/javascript" />
    <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/json" />
    <add enabled="true" mimeType="multipart/*" />
    <add enabled="false" mimeType="*/*" />
  </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
```

The actual response mime type starts with 'multipart/mixed' but varies depending on the boundary id appended to it.

```
Content-Type:multipart/mixed; boundary="0bb00cbc-234a-4264-87dc-60109719e79f"
```

The request is sending up an Accepted-Encoding header so I don't think the problem is there I think it is something to do with IIS match the mime type.

Any ideas would be awesome!

Thanks,

Jon

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this, and was able to get around this by using this NuGet package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.MessageHandlers.Compression/

This also supports the compression of the batch responses.

Info on how to use it is on the github page:
https://github.com/azzlack/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.MessageHandlers.Compression